# Computing the first n primes: an example from Clean Code revised for C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, primes

I'm trying to improve on examples from *Clean Code** while re-implementing them in C++. This time it's the Sieve of Eratosthenes prime-computing example from pp. 71-74.

Below is the original adapted for C++, without improvements:

.h

> ```
> class PrimeGenerator { 
> public:
>     PrimeGenerator() = default;
>     ~PrimeGenerator() = default;
>
>     static std::vector<unsigned> generatePrimes(unsigned maxValue);
>
> private:
>     static void uncrossIntegersUpTo(unsigned maxValue);
>     static void crossOutMultiples();
>     static unsigned determineIterationLimit();
>     static void crossOutMultiplesOf(unsigned i);
>     static bool notCrossed(unsigned i);
>     static void putUncrossedIntegersIntoResult();
>     static unsigned numberOfUncrossedIntegers();
>
>     static std::vector<bool> crossedOut;
>     static std::vector<unsigned> result; 
> };
> ```

.cpp

> ```
> std::vector<bool> PrimeGenerator::crossedOut;
> std::vector<unsigned> PrimeGenerator::result;
>
> std::vector<unsigned> PrimeGenerator::generatePrimes(unsigned maxValue)
> {
>     if (maxValue < 2)
>         return {};
>
>     uncrossIntegersUpTo(maxValue);
>     crossOutMultiples();
>     putUncrossedIntegersIntoResult();
>     return result;
> }
>
> void PrimeGenerator::uncrossIntegersUpTo(unsigned maxValue)
> {
>     crossedOut = std::vector<bool>(maxValue + 1, false);
>     crossedOut[0] = true;
>     crossedOut[1] = true;
> }
>
> void PrimeGenerator::crossOutMultiples()
> {
>     unsigned limit = determineIterationLimit();
>     for (size_t i = 2; i <= limit; ++i)
>     {
>         if (notCrossed(i))
>             crossOutMultiplesOf(i);
>     }
> }
>
> unsigned PrimeGenerator::determineIterationLimit()
> {
>     // Every multiple in the array has a prime factor that
>     // is less than or equal to the root of the array size,
>     // so we don't have to cross out multiples of numbers
>     // larger than that root.
>     double iterationLimit = std::sqrt(crossedOut.size());
>     return static_cast<unsigned>(iterationLimit);
> }
>
> void PrimeGenerator::crossOutMultiplesOf(unsigned i)
> {
>     for (size_t multiple = 2 * i; multiple < crossedOut.size(); multiple += i)
>     {
>         crossedOut[multiple] = true;
>     }
> }
>
> bool PrimeGenerator::notCrossed(unsigned i)
> {
>     return !crossedOut[i];
> }
>
> void PrimeGenerator::putUncrossedIntegersIntoResult()
> {
>     result = std::vector<unsigned>(numberOfUncrossedIntegers());
>     size_t j = 0;
>     for (size_t i = 2; i < crossedOut.size(); ++i)
>     {
>         if (notCrossed(i))
>             result[j++] = i;
>     }
> }
>
> unsigned PrimeGenerator::numberOfUncrossedIntegers()
> {
>     unsigned count = 0;
>     for (size_t i = 2; i < crossedOut.size(); ++i)
>     {
>         if (notCrossed(i))
>             count++;
>     }
>
>     return count;
> }
> ```

What we see here is a static class with static functions and members. We don't like these in C++, so it seems this code could be better served with a namespace and some free functions. Let's try - my improvement attempt coming below.

.h

```
namespace PrimeGenerator
{
    std::vector<unsigned> generatePrimes(unsigned maxValue);
}
```

.cpp

```
namespace {

std::vector<bool> uncrossIntegersUpTo(int maxValue)
{
    std::vector<bool> crossedOut(maxValue + 1, false);
    crossedOut[0] = true;
    crossedOut[1] = true;

    return crossedOut;
}

unsigned determineIterationLimit(size_t size)
{
    // Every multiple in the array has a prime factor that
    // is less than or equal to the root of the array size,
    // so we don't have to cross out multiples of numbers
    // larger than that root.
    double iterationLimit = std::sqrt(size);
    return static_cast<unsigned>(iterationLimit);
}

void crossOutMultiplesOf(unsigned i, std::vector<bool>& crossedOut)
{
    for (size_t multiple = 2 * i; multiple < crossedOut.size(); multiple += i)
    {
        crossedOut[multiple] = true;
    }
}

void crossOutMultiples(std::vector<bool>& crossedOut)
{
    unsigned limit = determineIterationLimit(crossedOut.size());
    for (size_t i = 2; i <= limit; ++i)
    {
        if (!crossedOut[i])
            crossOutMultiplesOf(i, crossedOut);
    }
}

std::vector<unsigned> putUncrossedIntegersIntoResult(const std::vector<bool>& crossedOut)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> result;
    for (size_t i = 2; i < crossedOut.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (!crossedOut[i])
            result.push_back(i);
    }

    return result;
}

}

namespace PrimeGenerator {

std::vector<unsigned> generatePrimes(unsigned maxValue)
{
    if (maxValue < 2)
        return {};

    auto crossedOut = uncrossIntegersUpTo(maxValue);
    crossOutMultiples(crossedOut);
    return putUncrossedIntegersIntoResult(crossedOut);
}

}
```

A quick summary of changes:
- I removed the class, leaving a single interface function in a `PrimeGenerator` namespace.
- The `numberOfUncrossedIntegers()` function didn't seem to make much sense, so I refactored `putUncrossedIntegersIntoResult(...)` to get rid of the former.
- `notCrossed(...)` would now need to have two parameters, so it stopped making sense either. It's gone now.

Now, I have two questions about my code. First of all, we now need to pass the `crossedOut` vector around, which is a downside compared to the previous design. Would you propose an alternative solution to mitigate this? Secondly, are there any extra places where I should have used `size_t` instead of `unsigned`?

Cheers!

**EDIT:**
I'd like to stress I care more about good software engineering and coding style here rather than making this algorithm as fast as possible. Though of course it should be correct.

---

* *Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship*, Robert C. Martin

Answer (score 2):

In general, we try to keep functions small and nice, but in your case, using so many functions is just weird.  For example, are you sure the `uncrossedIntegersUpTo` function is needed at all?  How about `determineIterationLimit`?  You can just handle them in the main function.

Also, `std::vector<bool>` is not like the normal `vector`.  It is not a container because it (usually) packs the `bool`s together to save space.  This may result in a significant increase in runtime.  (See Howard Hinnant's [On `vector<bool>`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html))  This is definitely a big mistake, but there is no trivial backwards compatible way to fix it at this stage.  You may have to consider working around it with, say, `std::vector<char>` in this case.

Now let's talk about types.  First, it is `std::size_t`, not `size_t`.  Second, your use of `unsigned` everywhere is like a "magic type" (analogous to magic numbers) — it will help to define an alias like

```
using number_t = unsigned;
```

And I think something like `std::uint_fast32_t` will be better in this case.  Also, `std::size_t` operates on sizes.  Are you sure you want to use it for numbers?

`std::sqrt` operates on floating point numbers and may cause precision problems here.  You may want to design some `isqrt` function for integers.

Putting these together, your code may be as simple as something like: (not tested)

```
// generate primes less than max
std::vector<number_t> generate_primes(number_t max)
{
    if (max < 2)
        return {};

    // You may need to use char or something like that
    std::vector<bool> table(max, false); // crossed out numbers
    table[0] = table[1] = true;

    const number_t limit = isqrt(max); // like that
    for (number_t i = 2; i < limit; ++i) {
        if (!table[i]) {
            for (number_t j = i * 2; j < max; ++j)
                table[j] = true;
        }
    }

    std::vector<number_t> result;
    for (number_t i = 2; i < max; ++i) {
        if (!table[i])
            result.push_back(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input! There are points I agree with, and some I disagree with, as in life :) Ad. Small functions. I do like small functions, and I don't think "it's just weird" is enough of a justification not to write them. Another thing I don't like are raw loops (S. Parent's talk on this is highly recommendable: https://youtu.be/W2tWOdzgXHA), so I'd insist on keeping `crossOutMultiples` along with `putUncrossedIntegersIntoResult` (but rename it). I do think you've got a point, though, and I'd include `crossOutMultiplesOf` in the former plus get rid of `determineIterationLimit`.

Comment: Ad. `std::vector<bool>`. I had a vague idea there was something wrong with it, but didn't know exactly what. Thanks!

Ad. `size_t` vs `std::size_t`. Oh right, `size_t` actually comes from the C compatibility header. True, we should prefer the namespaced one, though they're essentially the same, I think. `std::size_t` is not as convenient, however ;) Still, you're right.

Ad. `using number_t`. That's an interesting idea, thanks. Where *would you* use size_t, then?

Comment: Ad. `std::uint_fast32_t`. I didn't know about these types. Cool, thanks. Good for when you care about maximally optimising your algorithms for speed.
Ad. `isqrt`. I'm wondering if this is really necessary. I might be missing something, though, so could you clarify at what point do you see this becoming a problem?
Overall, thanks for the comments, I learned something. If I may give you some feedback, then I missed some arguments justifying your suggestions, such as with writing short functions.

Comment: I also have one comment to your own solution. Naming a vector or an array a 'table' doesn't really describe what it's for. `crossedOut`, which is not my idea, accomplishes this far better. Cheers!

Comment: @SG_90 There is nothing wrong with raw loops whatsoever.  What’s wrong is loops that really aren’t logically loops (e.g., zeroing a range).  `std::size_t` is used when you are dealing with size, e.g., as the size of an array.  The `fast` family of types are not directly related to speed ...  There is no objective way to judge which type is “fast,” and I just consider them as the “natural” type to use.  The alternative is the `least` family, which may actually incur performance overhead.  And `std::sqrt` may compute the square root of large numbers wrongly, and may be inefficient.

Comment: @SG_90 About short functions: everything good becomes bad when used to the extreme.  In general, short and nice functions are great, but too many of them just feels a bit wrong IMO.  In this case, you are logically doing one thing in this function, and things like cross tables aren’t a logically separate matter I think.  I am glad to see my answer is being read so carefully!

Answer (score 0):

- Starting cross-out from `size_t multiple = 2 * i` is a serious pessimization. Every multiple of `i` with other factor less than `i` has already been crossed out during previous passes, which dealt with these smaller primes. You should start with `size_t multiple = i * i`.
- Notice that computing `i * i` eliminates the need to compute `sqrt`. The outer loop written as

  ```
  for (size_t i = 2; i * i < crossedOut.size(); ++i)
  ```

  terminates in a very natural way. It may also be beneficial to store the square in a variable:

  ```
  for (size_t i = 2; (square = i * i) < crossedOut.size(); ++i) {
      crossOutMultiplesOf(square, i, crossedOut);
  }
  ```

  Now, passing both `i` and its square seems redundant. OTOH *not* passing the square forces the callee to recompute it. This is a very rare situation in which I'd advocate against factoring the loop into a function. Consider

  ```
  for (size_t i = 2; (square = i * i) < crossedOut.size(); ++i) {
      for (size_t multiple = square; multiple < crossedOut.size(); multiple += i) {
          crossedOut[multiple] = true;
      }
  }
  ```